# Espresso for ui-testing while doing network calls (RxJava-Project)

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso, ui-testing

I recently started with UI testing on android and I am using Espresso for that. How can I wait for my data calls to complete? I am using RxJava and espresso is not having an idling resource for Rxjava. So I noticed that I can do my own Idling Resource, but how should I do this? Especially when using the Schedulers.io().

I want to test that my button disables after an onClick() event. The button stays disabled until my network call is finished. I want to test this.

I found this module here by Ross Hambrick: https://github.com/stablekernel/RxEspresso but I really don't now how to use it.

If you could help me I would be verry happy!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps you also. stablekernel added a description how to use RxEspresso at their github-repo (https://github.com/stablekernel/RxEspresso).

Have fun doing ui-tests with RxEspresso.

Best regards
NullPointer